# How to handle concurrency if C/C++ Python3 extension hosting a http server and calling python code as request handler?

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, python-3.x, python-extensions

I try to create a Python extension which will host a HTTP server. When a particular request coming in, the extension calling a Python code from the extension consumer to handle the request. Since HTTP server is by-nature multi-thread, the controller/Python-code will be called in parallel.

According to [Python Document](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads), I try to do something like below (removed all error handling code branch to make it simpler)

```
static string CallingPythonFunc(string input)
{
    PyGILState_STATE gstate;
    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    PyObject *arglist;
    PyObject *result;

    /* Time to call the callback */

    PyGILState_Release(gstate);
    return output;
}
```

The `my_python_func` could be very simple like below:

```
def foo(input):
    return input+"123"
```

but apparently if there are two requests coming in at the same time, above code will deadlock.

I also found some other [sample1](https://gist.github.com/liuyu81/3473376),
 [sample2](https://gist.github.com/zed/3471699) and StackOverflow [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432471/calling-python-code-from-a-c-thread), [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470367/pyeval-initthreads-in-python-3-how-when-to-call-it-the-saga-continues-ad-naus). But seems both sample code create thread by itself, my case the thread is created by the http server. Two StackOverflow answers make feel confused. I thought my code above should wait for GIL available and then run the python call-back code, then get out from the critical section. But seems what I show above is not the case.

Comment: What is the Python source for `my_python_func`?

Comment: @Kevin, thanks for asking! I have updated the question with the sample of `my_python_func`.

Comment: Thank you @Cœur for cleaning up!

Comment: Once you reach 2000 reputation, you can do the same and freely improve Stack Overflow database. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I got the solution by talking to some guru of Python: I need to call `PyEval_InitThreads()` and wrap the code which creating non-Python threads with `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS`.